# How to check if row exists on database CodeIgniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3

So I'm having a bit of troubles with this query as it is the first time in which instead of checking for a value in a row, I'm checking if a row itself exists on database.

This is the problem that I'm facing:

**UPDATE:**

```
public function individualDiscountVerification($id){

        // Get postID
        $data['item']           =   $this->PublicStore_model->readPostID($id);
        $data['relationship']   =   $this->PublicStore_model->getPostRelationship($id);

        // Get Last Post ID
        $postID         =   $id;
        $activityTitle  =   $data['item']->title;

        // Verify Data
        $itemInCart = $this->PublicCart_model->verifyUserCartItem($postID);

        // Redirect if row does not exist -- HERE IS WHERE I NEED HELP
        if(!$itemInCart){

            // Set message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You first need to add it to you cart');

            // Redirect
            redirect('store/read/'.$id);


        // Redirect if seller is the same as the current userID
        } elseif($this->session->userdata('user_id') == $data['relationship']->user_id) {

            // Set message
            $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'You can not add discounts to your own products');

            // Redirect
            redirect('store/read/'.$id);

        } else {

            // Verify discount exists
            $discount       =   $this->input->post('discount_code');
            $discountCode   =   $this->PublicCart_model->verifySingleDiscount($discount);

            if(!$discountCode){

                // Set message
                $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'The discount has expired or is invalid');

                // Redirect
                redirect('store/read/'.$id);

            } else {

                // Get Last ID Data
                $discountID     =   $discountCode->discount_id;

                // Get Discount Type
                $discountType   =   $this->PublicCart_model->getIndividualDiscountID($discountID);

                // Verify data
                $verifyItemDiscount =   $this->PublicCart_model->verifySingleItemDiscountCode($postID, $discountID);

                if($discountType->type == 'percent' && $verifyItemDiscount != NULL?:'' && $discountID == $data['relationship']->discount_id){

                    // Update Post Array
                    $postData   =   array(
                        'price'         =>  round($data['relationship']->price * ((100 - $discountCode->amount) / 100), 2),
                        'discount_id'   =>  $discountID,
                    );
                    // Update Post Array
                    $this->PublicCart_model->updateUserCartItem($postID, $postData);

                    // Set message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'A percent discount type has been applied to your final price');

                    // Redirect
                    redirect('store/read/'.$data['item']->post_id);

                } elseif($discountID != $data['relationship']->discount_id){

                    // Set message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Percent discount is not attached to this product');

                    // Redirect
                    redirect('store/read/'.$data['item']->post_id);

                } elseif($discountType->type == 'float' && $verifyItemDiscount != NULL?:'' && $discountID == $data['relationship']->discount_id){

                    // Update Post Array
                    $originalprice  =   $data['relationship']->price;
                    $amount = $discountCode->amount;
                    $postData   =   array(
                        'price'         => $originalprice - $amount,
                        'discount_id'   =>  $discountID,
                    );
                    // Update Post Array
                    $this->PublicCart_model->updateUserCartItem($postID, $postData);

                    // Set message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('success', 'A float discount type has been applied to your final price');

                    // Redirect
                    redirect('store/read/'.$data['item']->post_id);

                } elseif($discountID != $data['relationship']->discount_id){

                    // Set message
                    $this->session->set_flashdata('error', 'Float discount is not attached to this product');

                    // Redirect
                    redirect('store/read/'.$data['item']->post_id);
                }

                // Activity Array
                $activityData   =   array();
                // Insert Activity
                $this->Activity_model->add($activityData);

            }
        }
    }
```

and here is the method in the model:

**UPDATE:**

```
  /*
  *
  * IS IN USER'S CART? -- FROM HERE AND BELOW IS FOR THE INDIVIDUAL ITEMS DISCOUNT
  *
  */
  public function verifyUserCartItem($postID){
    $query = $this->db->get($this->relationship, array(
      'post_id'   =>  $postID,
      'friend_id' =>  $this->session->userdata('user_id'),
      'type'      =>  $this->cartType,
    ));

    if($query->num_rows() > 0){
      return $query->row_array();
    } else {
      return null;
    }

  }
  /*
  *
  * DOES THE DISCOUNT EXISTS?; IF YES, WHAT TYPE OF DISCOUNT IT IS?
  *
  */
  public function verifySingleDiscount($discount){
    $query  =  $this->db->get_where($this->discounts, array(
      'code'  =>  $discount,
    ));
    return $query->row();
  }

  public function getIndividualDiscountID($discountID){
    $query  = $this->db->get_where($this->relationship, array(
      'discount_id' =>  $discountID,
      'status'      =>  $this->published,
    ));
    return $query->row();
  }
  /*
  *
  * IS THE DISCOUNT ATTACHED TO THE POST?; IF YES, UPDATE IT
  *
  */
  public function verifySingleItemDiscountCode($postID, $discountID){
    $query  = $this->db->get_where($this->relationship, array(
      'post_id'     =>  $postID,
      'discount_id' =>  $discountID,
      'status'      =>  $this->published,
    ));
    return $query->row();
  }

  public function updateUserCartItem($postID, $postData){
    $this->db->select('*');
    $this->db->where('friend_id', $this->session->userdata('user_id'));
    $this->db->where('post_id', $postID);
    $this->db->where('type', $this->cartType);
    $this->db->update($this->relationship, $postData);
  }
```

Note: As you can see I'm already using isset but that messes up the following blocks of code(I'll put the whole function if requested) which are not posted here; I already used `if empty` or `if var === false` but I'm still getting the same error.

Comment: what is that same error ?

Comment: It is not exactly the same error but I'm just trying to check if row does exist, otherwise redirect me to the specific page but if I do use the isset() function it retrieves the error I want but it messes up with the following block of code. Do you want me to edit the question and put the whole controller function?

Comment: Tried but did not work, it now skips the checking of whether or not the cart item is already in databse.

Answer (score 1):

try below in `verifyUserCartItem` function :

```
if($query->num_rows() > 0){
  return $query->row_array();
} else {
  return null;
}
```

and `if(!$itemInCart){` instead of `if(isset($itemInCart)){`

Comment: not working, if I go this way it "skips" the checking of whether or not the item is already in cart.....check my updated code again to see what I mean.

Comment: I don't understand. if `$itemInCart` would be `null` it means that there is no row for that in database. so redirect. isn't it what you want?

Comment: Yes, that's exactly what I want retrieving a message of "You first need to add to your cart" and what it actually does is retrieving the wrong message "Percent discount is not attached to this product" which is supposed to be displayed once it check the cart item IS IN the user's cart.... not when there is not cart item in the user's cart.... i'm having a headache over this, thanks for trying to help.

Comment: so it means that `$query->num_rows()` is more than 0. I suggest you to do `echo $query->num_rows()` to ensure that if your data is correct or not.

Answer (score 0):

For example:

```php
var_dump($this->db->where('id', $id)->get('TABLE_NAME')->num_rows());
```